# Rollback changes from a particular flyway version

Tags: git, flyway

I have added some changes in flyway let's say in version 20

ALTER TABLE
    xyz ADD COLUMN abc TINYINT(1);

Now, after a few DB migrations, we decide we don't need column 'abc' anymore and current flyway version is 35.

So, now I can currently look at two options, please suggest better one also, any other alternatives if present :

1. Create a new version 36 in which column is dropped which will work but kind of creates "garbage" files
2. Delete the file of version 20 (Not sure if it could break few things, particularly in production)

Comment: Flyway used two types of migration stratergies :

**Versioned migrations** have a version, a description and a checksum. 
The version must be unique. They are applied in order exactly once.

**Repeatable migrations** have a description and a checksum, but no version. 
Instead of being run just once, they are (re-)applied every time their checksum changes.

Since, we were using versioned approach, I stuck with step#1.

Keeping question open for better alternatives

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new version 36 in which column is dropped.